# I'm Trying to run my reactNative app on emulator but I'm getting this error in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, react-native

Error Image:

[image]

**Following is the error message**

The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:
{"originModulePath":"/home/junior/ReactNative/HelloWorld/index.js","targetModuleName":"@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault","message":"Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `/home/junior/ReactNative/HelloWorld/index.js`: Module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to [https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968%5CnTo) resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.\n  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.","errors":[{"description":"Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `/home/junior/ReactNative/HelloWorld/index.js`: Module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.\n  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`."}],"name":"Error","stack":"Error: Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `/home/junior/ReactNative/HelloWorld/index.js`: Module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to [https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968%5CnTo) resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.\n  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.\n    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/home/junior/ReactNative/HelloWorld/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:209:1301)\n    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/home/junior/ReactNative/HelloWorld/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:83:16)\n    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/home/junior/ReactNative/HelloWorld/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:238:485)\n    at Object.resolve (/home/junior/ReactNative/HelloWorld/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:180:25)\n    at dependencies.map.result (/home/junior/ReactNative/HelloWorld/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:311:29)\n    at Array.map ()\n    at resolveDependencies (/home/junior/ReactNative/HelloWorld/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:307:16)\n    at /home/junior/ReactNative/HelloWorld/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:164:33\n    at Generator.next ()\n    at step (/home/junior/ReactNative/HelloWorld/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:266:307)"}
processBundleResult
BundleDownloader.java:296
access$200
BundleDownloader.java:37
onResponse
BundleDownloader.java:174
execute
RealCall.java:153
run
NamedRunnable.java:32
runWorker
ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167
run
ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641
run
Thread.java:764

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands from the terminal ( in your project directory):

```
npm add @babel/runtime
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks mate it worked
 Can you explain what was wrong ?